# ClassCastException with find method for binary search tree for roster of students

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm having trouble implementing my find method for my binary search tree. I implemented my own version of a generic binary search tree and created a roster of students. The roster uses the binary search tree. However trying to find a student by ID gives me a ClassCastException error. Unsure why this is, what can I change within my find method to have it work properly? I can see that it is trying to cast Student to String, but don't know how to properly fix that. I think it may be because in my generic find method it uses e as a string comparing to Student, how can I have the string compare to the string in Student ID, rather than the object itself?

Error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: homework5.Student             
cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at java.lang.String.compareTo(String.java:111)
    at homework5.BST.find(BST.java:16)
    at homework5.Roster.find(Homework5.java:175)
    at homework5.Homework5.lookupStudent(Homework5.java:44)
    at homework5.Homework5.main(Homework5.java:13)
C:\Users\Devin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: 
Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

BST.java find method:

```
// Generic find method
public Node find(E e) {
    Node<E> current = root;

    // Loop until e.compare to current element is not equal to 0
    while (e.compareTo(current.element) != 0) {
        // if e.compare is less than 0 set current to current.left
        if (e.compareTo(current.element) < 0) {
            current = current.left;
        } // else if current is 0 or greater than 0 set current 
        // to current.right
        else {
            current = current.right;
        }
        // if current is null, return null
        if (current == null) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    // return current value when loop ends
    return current;
}
```

Main method:

```
public class Homework5 {

    static Roster rost = new Roster();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        addStudent();
        //displayAllStudents();
        lookupStudent("11114");
    }
}
```

lookUpStudent method:

```
// lookup a student in the roster
static void lookupStudent(String id) {
    if (rost.find(id) != null) {
        System.out.println(id + " found");
    } else {
        System.out.println(id + " not found");
    }
}
```

Roster.class:

```
class Roster {

    Student root;
    int numStudents;

    BST roster = new BST();

    public Roster() {
        root = null;
        numStudents = 0;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student st) {
        roster.insert(st);
        numStudents++;
    }

    public Student find(String id) {
        roster.find(id);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This is a valid error: you've made a mistake in your code. Hint: change `BST roster = new BST()` to `BST<Student> roster = new BST<>()`, and fix all compile errors that would show up. You'll be much closer to proper solution then.

Comment: Would I be better off not making my BST generic?

Comment: @BST, isn't it already generic? You say that "search method is generic", and you are using a `E` type to represent what's inside the `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding `student` object to the tree in `addStudent()` but using String id to find it, thus `e.compareTo(...)` trying to compare `String` with `Student`, hence the error

change the function `find` to smth like this

```
public Student find(String id) {
  return roster.find(new student(id));
}
```

make student implement `Comparable` interface and override the `compareTo` method

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Student other) {
    return this.id.compareTo(other.getId());
  }
}
```

Comment: In the compareTo method the compare action gives me an  error of "cannot find symbol"

Comment: I also have trouble adding the find method within the Student class, because roster also gives the error "cannot find symbol" because it's a seperate class and not visible to student?

Comment: @Devin this is just a draft, it’s hard to give a working solution without all your implemented classes and method, try the refactor compareTo now